# Cleanup Huge Git Repository

Tags: python, git, newrelic, inotify

My company has a single git repository which is over 15 years and is really massive with about 60% of it which can be archived. I want to find these scripts (python, perl, ruby, java etc) and create a new git repository with only frequently used scripts. The scripts also have cross dependencies.

One solution that I thought was to setup inotify to watch over the files in git repo and collect the names of recently accessed scripts, collect data over few months and then create new repo based on that data. Not sure how efficient it would be though.

Another solution I thought was to use git commit date for each file and remove files which are over 5 years old.

Could anyone let me know of an efficient solution to cleanup this mess ? Or any tool similar to NewRelic that would monitor the filesystem ?

Comment: Note that removing 60% of the repo will reduce the size to roughly one third, which does not sound like it would make a huge difference. Something to take into account when considering more involved procedures.

Comment: lol. you've got a swamp? good luck with that. You have to go for _at least_ a full year, because you've got no idea what might get invoked on a yearly basis . . .  manually, by some guy you've never met whose job you've never heard of in an office you didn't know existed.  There's no assigned responsibility in a swamp like that. I've never seen any company, ever, successfully clean one up.  The political exposure for a screwup is just too intolerable.

Comment: A 60% reduction is massive.  I'm happy anytime I can get a 10% reduction.  As crazy as it sounds, we've had good luck just nuking everything that looked unneeded, then bringing them back if anybody complained they were missing.  Obviously this depends on your business environment whether or not it is viable.

Comment: Haha.. that sounds like a good plan @AndrewC... and yeah 60% is quite huge for us as well. In addition, while analyzing I even found .mp3, .wav, .tar.bz files... It is crazy and yeah its a swamp [at]jthill

Comment: Do you want to reduce the Git's history to address clone times and on-disk size of the .git directory, or is it the checked-out size that's problematic?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. Is the 15-year git history slowing things down when cloning? If so, maybe just do a shallow git clone instead? (i.e. A shallow cone doesn't download the history.)

As Thilo pointed out, cutting the repo in half isn't going to make things *that* much faster.

But if the scripts are really that disorganized, it's highly likely that some of them need to be rewritten, documented, etc.  If you just move the scripts forward, it's likely you are moving lots of inefficiencies forward too. I'd pick them off one at at time, and give them a little love, test them, etc.

One idea: You can use `strace -ff -o strace.out ./myscript` to figure out what other files a script opens.

Comment: The main problem is that we are not able to take good advantage of git like branching because of the performance problems. It is a big pile of mess and is growing day by day. So keeping the code base clean and up-to-date with frequently used scripts is my target :)

Comment: @user2896673: Why would the size of the repository prevent branching?